# Password is sent to a console in open text when use pexpect

Tags: pexpect

I'm writing a simple script to with pexpect module to implement some commands on network devices. 
I use getpass module as well to save the password to a variable, but when I run a script I can see a password in my console.

```
import csv
import getpass
import pexpect
pswd = getpass.getpass('Please enter your TACACS Password:')
list1 = open('./list.csv', 'rU')
csvfile = csv.reader(list1)
num = 1


for row in csvfile:
    child = pexpect.spawn('ssh ' + str(row[0]))
    child.logfile = log_configen
    print 'Trying to reach ' + str(row[0])
    child.expect('password:')
    child.sendline(pswd)
```

Comment: Is there any more code after that? Do you print any output from `child`?

Comment: May I ask you what is the ide you are using?

Comment: It gets written in a log file.

Comment: I have same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994624/pexpect-python-password-hidden
Is this issue solved ?